# Is it possible to set up an Apple ID for a small business that isn't tied to a phone?

Tags: apple-id, mac-appstore

I work in IT for a small business (not enterprise) that has maybe 40 macOS devices. Sometimes when purchasing or downloading a program, we're required to sign in with an Apple ID. Right now we have a number of Apple IDs created at different times, which are associated with various cellphone numbers and iOS devices. I'd like to create one (or a limited number) of IDs we can use as a company, that will still allow people to access the App Store and any purchases that have been made there even if the person who's cellphone it is associated with isn't working that day (or leaves the company etc).

I've tried several times to create new accounts without associating it with a phone, but I can't find a way to create something that doesn't ping my personal cellphone whenever I do something like sign into the App Store on a new computer while setting up a macbook for someone. It seems crazy to buy a pay-as-you-go cellphone just to receive 2 Factor text messages, or walk up to reception and answer the main company line to get the code every time, but that seems to be where we're at. Or, I guess, make a new account every time we lose access to the old one, and re-pay for any App Store purchases.

Comment: I should mention I have seen some things that say that it was once possible to disable two-factor authentication within 2 weeks of account creation, but unless I'm missing something that is no longer true.

Comment: There is no restriction that 2FA is a unique number. Multiple accounts can use the same 2FA phone numbers. I know this since I have a number listed for 2FA on my account that somebody else uses as well.

Comment: Are you trying to use a consumer Apple ID for a business? Have you investigated what Apple provides specifically for business?

Comment: @Gilby As far as I can tell Apple doesn't have anything for business that's not an enterprise level solution that comes with a bunch of fees, and it just ends up being one admin account per administrator, each tied to a cellphone. We may have to just go down that route though.

Comment: @Ezekiel Elin my problem isn't that a phone number has already been used for an apple ID my problem is that if IT tech #1 makes an Apple ID, purchases and installs a bunch of software using their cellphone as a 2factor device, and then goes on vacation, IT tech #2 can't install that purchased software without IT tech #1's cellphone.

Comment: So yes - you need to make a company or department Apple ID in a controlled setting first, and have techs sign into that account on their phones in the App Store section.

Comment: But if Alice makes an account it_dept@company.com, and connects it to her cellphone, then only Alice holding her physical phone can log into it. If Alice is at home asleep, her fellow tech Bob can't sign into it on a new computer. So any apps Alice buys on behalf of the company, Bob can't install on a machine. For every other vender we have a central account several techs use, but Apple requires a physical phone be attached to each account.

Comment: Unless theres a way to assign multiple phones to the same account?